# Presentation with code is cut off at the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reveal.js, highlight.js

I am preparing a presentation with reveal.js where I would like to show some lines of code.

If I just have a slide with the code, it is shown in a panel with a scrollbar containing the complete code:
[image]

However, If I am preceding the code block with a header:

```
<section id="slide-12">
<h3>Example 1: my first d3 visualization</h3>
<pre><code>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
  <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- also save this file as unicode-8 ! -->
  &lt;head&gt;
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  &lt;/head&gt;

  &lt;body&gt;
    <h1>My meetup groups are:</h1>
    <svg width="500" height="500"></svg>

    <script>    
      var meetupGroupSizes = [1943, 1073, 297];

      function display(mydata){
        var anchor = d3.select("svg");

        selection = anchor.selectAll("circle")
          .data(mydata);

        selection.style("fill", "orange"); // update selection

        selection.enter() // enter selection
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return (i + 1) * 100;})
          .attr("cy", 300)
          .attr("r", 0)
          .style("fill", "white")
          .transition()
          .delay( function(d, i) { return i * 500;} )
          .duration(2000)
          .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d / Math.PI);})
          .style("fill", "steelblue");

        selection.exit() // exit selection
          .remove();
      }

      display(meetupGroupSizes);      
    </script>
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;

</code></pre>

</section>
```

Then the content of the scrollable code panel is cut off at the bottom (/html tag is missing).

The result is this:
[image]

I have two questions:
1) How do I display the complete code block even after the header ?
2) How can I display the code block without the scrollable panel (decreasing the font size)?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How do I display the complete code block even after the header?

My guess is that the `max-height` of that code block is causing it to go off the page. I use markdown with reveal, so I don't have exactly the same set-up as you. However, using the Inspect feature in Google Chrome I was able to see my code block's height comes from the reveal theme's CSS (in my case it's `beige.css`):

```css
.reveal pre code {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  word-wrap: normal;
  }
```

I'm not sure what theme you're using, but if you can override the `max-height` value and make it smaller (by the height of your H1), it should work to make the scrollable area fit.

> 2) How can I display the code block without the scrollable panel (decreasing the font size)?

In my case, it's again related to `beige.css`, namely the `font-size`:

```css
.reveal pre {
    [...]
    font-size: 0.55em;
    [...]
}
```

I reduced this value in the Inspect view of Chrome until all the text fit in my code block. Then you just need to take that number and figure out how to override it.

Putting both your questions together, the following assumes `max-height:300px` and `font-size:0.35em` are the right values (but they will depend on your theme):

```html
<pre><code style="max-height:300px;font-size:0.35em">
...
</code></pre>
```